# how do I use a Arduino Library with a second Sercom / second I2c bus

Tags: arduino, i2c

I'm preparing myself to be ostracized for not googling this appropriately but I have been on the search for a solution for the past day and a half, tried dozens of things and nothing is working. I am trying to move a device ([Adafruit ADS1115](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085)) off of the standard I2C Bus, which is shared my several devices, onto its own I2C bus. the reason is the ADS1115 seems to cause everything else on the bus to stop responding. I've gone through the [Library files](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15/tree/master) looking for a configuration to change but nothing seems to make a difference. I tried the [non-blocking](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15/blob/master/examples/nonblocking/nonblocking.ino) example code and it is not working for me either. I am using freeRTOS since I desperately need threading and I think the non blocking code might not be working well because of that. I think using a separate I2C port might fix the issue but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it. There are a bunch of essentially the same examples out there but they only show how to create the port using the wire Library but the Adafruit library seems to be a layer above that? If anybody out there can show me how to just modify the [non-blocking](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADS1X15/blob/master/examples/nonblocking/nonblocking.ino) example code to use a different set of pins I would be so greatful. I am using a [Adafruit grand central m4](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-grand-central/pinouts) and want to use the SDA1 & SCL1 on pins 25 & 24.

Comment: I don't own any SAMD board, but from reading the source code of Adafruit Arduino-samd core, its version of `Wire` Library has a construct which allows you to specifies the Sercom and SDA, SCL pins  `Wire myI2c(SERCOM * s, uint8_t pinSDA, uint8_t pinSCL)`. See [source code](https://github.com/adafruit/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/master/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp#L34). I think you need to create an I2C instance using the construct before you using the ADS1115.

Comment: Further based on the information [here](https://github.com/adafruit/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/master/variants/grand_central_m4/variant.h#L228-L238), to use the construct, it will be something like `Wire myI2c(&PERIPH_WIRE1, SDA1, SCL1);`

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I have tried that. I suppose I just don't understand how to establish the relation between that and the library I am trying to use.

Comment: `bool begin(uint8_t i2c_addr = ADS1X15_ADDRESS, TwoWire *wire = &Wire);` specify the second parameter of `begin`

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out. I thought I had read that you can use any sercom and assumed something in my formatting was incorrect. You can **NOT** use any sercom. I found a reference to sercom6 on the [Pinout Diagram](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/115/366/original/adafruit_products_Adafruit-Grand-Central-M4-Express-Pinout.png?1663982143)

Here is working code for reference:

```c
#include <Adafruit_ADS1X15.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define pinSDA1 25 
#define pinSCL1 24

Adafruit_ADS1115 ads;  /* Use this for the 16-bit version */
//Adafruit_ADS1015 ads;     /* Use this for the 12-bit version */

TwoWire I2cB(&sercom6, pinSDA1, pinSCL1);

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

  Serial.println("Getting differential reading from AIN0 (P) and AIN1 (N)");
  Serial.println("ADC Range: +/- 6.144V (1 bit = 3mV/ADS1015, 0.1875mV/ADS1115)");

  // The ADC input range (or gain) can be changed via the following
  // functions, but be careful never to exceed VDD +0.3V max, or to
  // exceed the upper and lower limits if you adjust the input range!
  // Setting these values incorrectly may destroy your ADC!
  //                                                                ADS1015  ADS1115
  //                                                                -------  -------
  // ads.setGain(GAIN_TWOTHIRDS);  // 2/3x gain +/- 6.144V  1 bit = 3mV      0.1875mV (default)
  // ads.setGain(GAIN_ONE);        // 1x gain   +/- 4.096V  1 bit = 2mV      0.125mV
  // ads.setGain(GAIN_TWO);        // 2x gain   +/- 2.048V  1 bit = 1mV      0.0625mV
  // ads.setGain(GAIN_FOUR);       // 4x gain   +/- 1.024V  1 bit = 0.5mV    0.03125mV
  // ads.setGain(GAIN_EIGHT);      // 8x gain   +/- 0.512V  1 bit = 0.25mV   0.015625mV
  // ads.setGain(GAIN_SIXTEEN);    // 16x gain  +/- 0.256V  1 bit = 0.125mV  0.0078125mV

  if (!ads.begin(0x48, &I2cB)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize ADS.");
    while (1);
  }

  // Start the first conversion.
  ads.startADCReading(MUX_BY_CHANNEL[0], /* continuous= */ false);
}

void loop(void)
{
  // Serial.println("hello again");
  // delay(1000);
  // return;

  // If we don't have new data, skip this iteration.
  if (!ads.conversionComplete())
    return;

  int16_t results = ads.getLastConversionResults();

  Serial.print("Differential: ");
  Serial.print(results);
  Serial.print("(");
  Serial.print(ads.computeVolts(results));
  Serial.println("mV)");

  // Start another conversion.
  ads.startADCReading(MUX_BY_CHANNEL[0], /* continuous= */ false);

  delay(1000);
}
```